# How to track number of changes occured in a column? T-SQL - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

For example, i have a column named EmployeeName.

Every time a user changes/fix his name, i need to keep a count. If he changes his name twice, then count is 2. Also, i need to store the time of every change employee makes on EmployeeName e.g. if the name essentially is James and time created is 9:00 AM and then employee changes to John on 11:00 AM, i need to preserve this new time and new value as well as the previous one which is James at 9:00 AM.

I hope its clear! Thank you guys...Best Answer will be chosen...

If this requires a trigger, giving a sketchy pseudo-code will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First up - if not already implemented, highly advisable to have employees identified by a permanent identifier (i.e. NOT EmployeeName) and so you can keep track on everything.

If you want to use a trigger, you could use an AFTER UPDATE trigger and look for a change to the name using `if update(EmployeeName)`.

If that's been updated, you could increment the count column on the Employee table at the same time. Use the `inserted` table to identify those entries which have been updated. (Is the count essential? If you are storing a history of the name changes, I don't think it's necessary to have a count column - it's redundant informaiton.)

You would then add a row to your employee name history table that holds the details of this change with the current timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

A trigger will suffice. Triggers should be as simple and lightweight as possible, so just insert an entry into some logging table, and compute aggregates on it later.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2008 you have the new Change Data Capture feature, you could use that to get the number of changes, plus the changes made: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/derekc/archive/2008/01/28/60469.aspx

Sample Northwind code, as links can die over time:

```
EXEC Sp_cdc_enable_table 
  humanresources , 
  employee , 
  'HumanResources_Employee' , 
  1 , 
  dbo 


UPDATE humanresources.employee 
SET    ContactId = 1 
WHERE  employeeid = 1 

DECLARE @begin_lsn BINARY(10), @end_lsn BINARY(10)

SELECT @begin_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('humanresources_employee')
SELECT @end_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn()

SELECT * FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_humanresources_employee(@begin_lsn, @end_lsn, 'all');
```