# How to query the number of changes that have been made to a particular column in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a database with a column that I want to query the amount of times it has changed over a period of time. For example, I have the username, user's level, and date. How do I query this database to see the number of times the user's level has changed over x amount of years?

(I've looked in other posts on stackoverflow, and they're telling me to use triggers. But in my situation, I want to query the database for the number of changes that has been made. If my question can't be answered, please tell me what other columns might I need to look into to figure this out. Am I supposed to use Lag for this? )

Comment: Unless you have been saving that information all along, that's not possible.

Comment: [Similar Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736934/how-to-track-number-of-changes-occured-in-a-column-t-sql-sql-server)

Comment: What database management system are you using? SQL standard has no default way to count number of updates/deletes performed on a table/column. That information is probably not retrievable by now.

Comment: Do you have multiple rows for each user, with different levels ad dates? In that case, it's possible.

Comment: I wasn't able to fully capture the entire database today when I glimpsed at it, I will update this question tomorrow. I was just brainstorming methods I could use to figure this question out. thank you

Answer (score 2):

A database will not inherently capture this information for you. Two suggestions would be to either store your data as a time series so instead of updating the value you add a new row to a table as the new current value and expire the old value. The other alternative would be to just add a new column for tracking the number of updates to the column you care about. This could be done in code or in a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heard of the LOG term ?
You have to create a new table, in wich you will store your wanted changes.
I can imagine this solution for the table:

- id - int, primary key, auto increment
- table - the table name where the info has been changed
- table_id - the information unique id from the table where changes
  have been made
- year - integer
- month - integer
- day - integer

knowin this, you can count everything

Comment: even if you do so, you would use a timestamp instead of year, month and day.

Comment: true, you should add a timestamp field, but my 3 fields are also usefull; you can do so much with them

Answer (score 0):

In case you are already keeping track of the level history by adding a new row with a different `level` and `date` every time a user changes `level`:

```
SELECT username, COUNT(date) - 1 AS changes
FROM table_name
WHERE date >= '2011-01-01'
GROUP BY username
```

That will give you the number of changes since Jan 1, 2011. Note that I'm subtracting `1` from the `COUNT`. That's because a user with a single row on your table has never *changed* levels, that row represents the user's initial level.

Comment: I'm conceptually thinking about your implementation right here, and I am wondering does this work on a database that already has 10 years of data on it for example? Would I set the date to 10 years ago to find the count of how many times that data has been updated?

Comment: It will work if you haven't been deleting or overwriting the `levels` over the years, but adding new rows instead. Otherwise it should give zero changes for every user.